# Can I open several dialog on top of each other in JQM?

Tags: jquery-mobile

As the question says I am interested to know if it is possible to open more than one dialog in JQM.

Thanks in advance,
Sincerely Babak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

As long as the page structure complies with JQM documentation it is possbile to open dialogs on top of other dialogs by calling

```
$.mobile.changePage('#page-id',  {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog'}    )   ;
```